# R programming: How does dataframe$column[<boolean>] = <value> work?

Tags: r, dataframe

This

```
df = data.frame(c(-2,-1,1,2), NA)
colnames(df) <- c("values", "pos_neg")
flag <- with(df, values < 0)
df$pos_neg[flag] = "negative"
df$pos_neg[!flag] = "positive"
```

gives me this

[image]

And it works as intended. The problem is that I'm not really sure how or why it does. What happens exactly if I put a boolean value into the brackets? Up to now I thought a dataframe is an array and I can access values only by number (`df[1]`) or by name if available (`df["pants"]`).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little easier to see if you look at the subsetting after the values are not all `NA`:

```r
df <- data.frame(values = c(-2,-1,1,2), 
                 pos_neg = NA)
flag <- df$values < 0

df$pos_neg[flag] <- "negative"
df$pos_neg[!flag] <- "positive"
```

The first important concept here is that a data frame is a list (with a class, some restrictions and lots of methods, but still a list) of variables ("columns"), not a two-dimensional array (a matrix). Thus, `$` or `[[` subsetting pulls out a single variable, which is a single vector, so

```r
df$pos_neg
#> [1] "negative" "negative" "positive" "positive"
```

You can subset any vector with a logical vector, so logical subsetting works just like `c('a', 'b')[c(FALSE TRUE)]` does:

```r
df$pos_neg[flag]
#> [1] "negative" "negative"
df$pos_neg[!flag]
#> [1] "positive" "positive"
```

Using `<-` to assign to those subsets works here because you are supplying a length-1 vector that is getting recycled to fit the subset.

---

Using `[` subsetting with two parameters (for rows and columns) on a data frame, e.g. `df[2:3, 'values']` is in some regards more complicated, even if more intuitive from the matrix analogue. In particular, the `[.data.frame` method defaults to `drop = TRUE`, which can make it unclear if it will return another data frame or a vector. Most of the time this doesn't matter, but it can cause bugs in programmatic usages.

Using `[` subsetting with a single parameter on a data frame, e.g. `df[1]`, works like `[` does on a list, subsetting columns by name, index, or logical mask and always returning another list of the same class (i.e. another data frame).

Comment: You might also point them to the nice help pages: `?"["` and `?[.data.frame`.